# Spring Boot Controller returning a Mono of a scala.concurrent.Future

Tags: java, spring, scala, akka, reactor

I am running an Akka actor system inside on Spring Boot application. I have a set of Actors running.

From my Controller class I call my service class that, using the Actor ask pattern, sends a message to an actor and expects a response. Below is the service method code:

```
public Mono<Future<SportEventDetailed>> getEventBySportAndLeagueId(Integer sportId, Integer leagueId) {
    final ActorSelection actorSelection = bootstrapAkka.getActorSystem().actorSelection("/user/some/path");
    final ActorMessage message = new ActorMessage()

    final CompletionStage<Future<SportEventDetails>> futureCompletionStage = actorSelection.resolveOne(Duration.ofSeconds(2))
            .thenApplyAsync(actorRef ->
                        Patterns.ask(actorRef, message, 1000)
                        .map(v1 -> (SportEventDetails) v1, ExecutionContext.global())
                )
                .whenCompleteAsync((sportEventDetailsFuture, throwable) -> {
                    // Here sportEventDetailsFuture is of type scala.concurrent.Future
                    sportEventDetailsFuture.onComplete(v1 -> {
                        final SportEventDetails eventDetails = v1.get();
                        log.info("Thread: {} | v1.get - onComplete - SED: {}", Thread.currentThread(), eventDetails);
                        return eventDetails;
                    }, ExecutionContext.global());
                });

    return Mono.fromCompletionStage(futureCompletionStage);
}
```

While the controller code is as simple as

```
@GetMapping(path = "{sportId}/{leagueId}")
public Mono<Future<SportEventDetails>> getEventsBySportAndLeagueId(@PathVariable("sportId") Integer sportId, @PathVariable("leagueId") Integer leagueId) {
    return eventService.getEventBySportAndLeagueId(sportId, leagueId);
}
```

When a client calls this endpoint it either gets `{"success":true,"failure":false}` or `null` (as a string).

I suspect the issue for the `null` response is the `scala.concurrent.Future` is not completed before the response is sent to the client - but I don't understand why it would not complete on time because I would assume the Mono would wait for the future to complete

The issue here is that `Patterns.ask` returns a `scala.concurrent.Future<SportEventDetails>` and I could not find a way to convert the scala Future to a Java `CompletableFuture<SportEventDetails>` or `CompletionStage<SportEventDetails>`.

So, my question is: how can I return to the client the json representation of `SportEventDetails` when using the Akka's Patterns.ask(...) model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Future`, `Mono` and `CompletionStage` are three implementations of the same concept, a value that may or may not be here yet. You will need a way to transform them into the same type and then a way to "flatten" the nested type. `Mono.fromCompletionStage` is such a method as it turns a `CompletionStage` into a `Mono`.

Easiest is will be to avoid getting a `Future` and the flattening completely:

In the more recent Java versions (2.5.19 or newer):
There are `ask` overloads taking a `java.time.Duration` timeout you will get a return value of `CompletionStage<SportEventDetail>`. There is also `ask` overloads which takes an `ActorSelection` so that you do not have to first resolve and then ask when resolve completes:

```
CompletionStage<SportEventDetail> futureSportEventDetails = 
  Patterns.ask(selection, message, Duration.ofSeconds(3))
return Mono.fromCompletionStage(futureSportEventDetails);
```

In older versions of Akka (2.4.2 and later I think) you should be able to find similar signatures in `akka.pattern.PatternsCS`.

If you are on an even older version and cannot upgrade you probably will have to provide your own converter method from `Future<T>` to `CompletionStage<T>` or `Mono<T>` that registers an `onComplete` listener on the future and completes an instance of the destination type.